# Select distinct records from database with condition using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have table of 100 records, in some records the first and last column are the same. I need distinct records on the basis of first and last columns.

For example if first and last columns in 5 rows are the same, then make it distinct and return only one record from the database. I hope you understand my question.

The table looks like this:

```
FirstField    2ndField  Last Field
----------------------------------
a              dd         10
a              dd         20
b              ff         50
a              gg         10
a              ng         10

DB.Information.Distinct().ToList();
```

Expected output:

```
a dd 10
a dd 20
b ff 50
```

Comment: Use a `GroupBy`

Comment: Have you already written any query for this? Can you share it here? Also can you share the sample data from the table with expected output ?

Comment: @TheGeneral how to use GroupBy ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i tried that code See updated question.

Comment: [How to use GroupBy](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+how+to+use+groupby&oq=C%23+how+to+use+groupby&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.5064j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes i checked i am going to run the code.

Comment: @TanvirArjel i will upadate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
var distinctRecords = DB.Information.GroupBy(i => new {i.FirstField, i.LastField})
              .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also distinct with multiple columns using `Distinct()`

```
var informations = DB.Information.Select(x=> new { x.FirstField , x.LastField }).Distinct().ToList();
```

here first we select columns as `anonymous-type` which you want to distinct

like this you can distinct with multiple column without `GroupBy` in linq.